# MySql on Duplicate Key Update returning the table modified

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but returning the results which were changed

```
INSERT INTO `tableName` (`a`,`b`,`c`) VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `a`=VALUES(`a`), `b`=VALUES(`b`), `c`=VALUES(`c`);
```

Is it possible to return for each row where there was an update what was the old value and with what value was replaced?

for example, if the original table contains

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q | w |
| 4 | a | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | x |

The Sql return to be something like a JSON

```
{1 : {'b' (column name): {'from': 'q', 'to': '2'}, 'c' (column name) : {'from': 'w', 'to': '3' }},
2 : {'b': {'from': 'a', 'to': '5'}},
3 : {'c': {'from': 'x', 'to': '9'}}}
```

There may be situations in which one update can update multiple rows, in this case, just the first one should be returned (or all of them if is complicated to implement)

Is there any magic that I can do to return the above JSON or any other format but with the correct data?

LATER EDIT:

I have created a new column and I am saving in it the old value

```
INSERT INTO `table`(
    `a`,
    `b`,
    `c`,
    `d`
 )
VALUES(1, 7, 'us', null),(6, 8, 'us', null)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE
    `d` = CASE WHEN `b` = VALUES(`b`) THEN `d` ELSE `b`
END,
`b` = VALUES(`b`), 
`c` = VALUES(`c`);
```

Having this column (with the old value) and not taking in consideration my initial request above (the JSON fromated response), is it possible to return all the rows in which I have a `d` (column) value taking in consideration that there may be other queries updating other rows in the table? and if yes, how can I do it, and how can I revert the `d` column to a null value keeping tha values which were in the db?

Comment: you could add a flag column and set the flag to 1 within your on duplicate key update clause. then, select the rows where the flag is 1 and clear the flag for all rows afterwards. this will not be concurrency-safe, but you could do this in a temporary copy of the table to make it so

Comment: The table has twenty million rows, and the insert/update in batches of 30k rows. Mostly there are updates

Comment: that doesn’t rule out what i said. you could as well insert the new items into a temptable first, join the two tables, resulting in the keys that will get updated. do your insert / update afterwards, read the temptable and delete it. even with 30k rows per batch that should be a rather fast process, proper indexing provided.

Comment: Not sure I understand your first comment. How do I get the old value and the updated value if I just set a flag? Or do you recomend saving that as a text in the new column? And what happens when multiple queries are updating the BD in the same time?

Comment: you can’t run concurrent updates, because of table locking. Besides that, temporary tables are always local to the session they are created in and don’t interfere with each other. And yes, the idea was that you store all needed data in your temptable

Comment: Can you please show me an example? I don;t know how I can save in a new temporary table in un update